# How do I get the text inside of an element using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So, I'm trying to get the text inside of all of the elements with the class names "letter-grade" and "course-name".

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
grades = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('letter-grade').__getattribute__('text')
classes = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('course-name').__getattribute__('text')
print(grades)
print(classes)
```

I've also tried doing `print(grades.text)` & `print(classes.text)`, to no avail.

Comment: Post your relevant HTML?

Comment: Hi! Any updates? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Yup, it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @BlueCyclone, ok, in this case, please accept my answer -- click on the tick near my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the following code:

```
grades = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("letter-grade")
classes = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("course-name")

grades_text = [grade.text for grade in grades]
classes_text = [class_.text for class_ in classes]

print(grades_text)
print(classes_text)
```

It' called list comprehension in Python (3th and 4th lines above). For getting the text from an element the `text` attribute/property is used from Selenium.

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('letter-grade')
    for element in elements:
    print element.text
```

**if you want to get attribute text**

```
    item = element.get_attribute("attribute name")
    print item.text
```

also you can't use `find_elements_by_class_name` if you are dealing with single web element, you can always refer `find_element_by_class_name` while dealing with individual element. `find_elements_by_class_name` will return list and you need to iterate through that list when you are dealing with list of web elements.